# Is there a better project pattern for a Winfoms app than the MDI Application?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, project-template

It litters my app with nonsense like File Open and Save, Edit- Copy and Paste, etc. as if I'm trying to build a better notepad, that can have multiple confounded text files open at once. Most business apps use a database and forms. Surely by 2013 MS could have created a project template for a useful application.

Are there any third party project templates out there that cater for non-delusional development scenarios? Something like DevExpress's XAF projects etc? I would use that if not for the cost that is prohibitive to me.

Comment: There's something strange in your question. `File - New Project - Windows Templates`. I have at least 10 different templates

Comment: @Steve, right at the top of my question, in the title in fact, I specify I'm looking for a template for a **Winforms app**, and only one out of those *eleven* templates is a Winforms Application. I hope your lack of reading comprehension is not the reason for my downvote.

Comment: Absolutely not. I don't downvote lightly

Comment: Still I find no MDI application between my templates. Now I am puzzled. (VS 2012?)

Comment: Apologies @Steve, it is the plain Windows forms application, with the subsequent addition of the MDI form that causes the mess I refer to. I have long just come to see this combo as the "MDI Template'.

Comment: @ProK why would anyone want a winforms application template? I'd rather have a VB6 application template as well... or maybe a QBasic one... Creating new winforms projects from stratch should be disallowed by Visual Studio.. for the sake of us all.

Comment: Well, there are other kinds of project that could benefit from a premade template: a RibbonUI application, an Outlook style, a Wizard like form. A premade template would help a lot. Now that I think at it better I will upvote the question.

Comment: @Steve My point is that it makes no sense to créate new projects in winforms, the same way it makes no sense to créate new projects in QBasic.

Comment: What's wrong with MDI app? If you are using 3rd party components, they are also likely to have MDI support. Devexpress, for example. It has nothing to do with business or non-business. UI is something you will have least trouble with (if nothing fancy). It's the business logic being a problem, performance, scalability and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is 2013 and Microsoft does have project types for business applications.  But you won't find them in the `Windows Forms` templates.  Microsoft is not investing any time or money in changing Winforms.  What you see in the Winforms templates are circa 2005.

That's not to say that Microsoft doesn't have project templates that cater to business developers with databases.

The places to look are in other project types (for example)

- ASP.NET Dynamic Data
- LightSwitch

If you want to stick with Winforms, you might check the Online section of the File\New\Project dialog for other template types.